# Calculate euclidean distance from a set in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array S(i) which contains all of the index values of the x coordinates j which are close to i, i.e. if S(1) = {2,3} this means that x2 and x3 are close to x1. In total I have S(1), ..., S(N) sets.

So this part of the code **works fine:**

```
arr = np.array([[1,3], [2,8],[3,1],[6,18], [9,8]]) 

arr = [item[0] for item in arr] #Extract x-coordinates

def Si(x): #This is the set i want to use
    return [[j for j in range(len(x)) if np.abs(x[j] - x[i]) < 2] for i in range(len(x))]
```

Now i have a subscript of j's, I want to calculate the euclidean distance between (x_i,y_i) to each (x_j,y_j) in S(i), e.g for i=1, if S(1) = {7}, find distance between (x_1, y_1) and (x_7, y_7), for i=2, if S(2) = {3,9}, find distance between (x_2,y_2) and (x_3,y_3) and (x_2,y_2) and (x_9,y_9) and repeat for each i.

I don't know how to implement this, i'm really confused! Here is a Euclidean distance code which finds it for ALL values in the array, but not in the set which i want.

```
def euc_dist(arr):
  
    arr_x = (arr[:,0,np.newaxis].T - arr[:,0,np.newaxis])**2 ##x-coordinates
    arr_y = (arr[:,1,np.newaxis].T - arr[:,1,np.newaxis])**2 ##y-coordinates
    arr = np.sqrt(arr_x + arr_y)

    return arr
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
S = Si(arr) # get the array
def my_fn(i): # take the value of i
    euc_dists = []
    for j in S[i]: # iterate over j's in S[i]
        if i!= j:
            dist = np.linalg.norm(arr[i]-arr[j]) # euclidean distance
            euc_dists.append(dist)
    return euc_dists
```

Comment: Thanks! And to speed things up, how to ensure it doesn't find the distance of itself?

Comment: ideally, your S(i) should not contain the same index of `i` if you want to ensure it doesn't find the distance of itself. but I have also added the condition in the answer.